# UILabel text wrap not working in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, word-wrap

I have a UILabel and it should display the text how much long it would be .So gone for the concept of UILineBreakModeWordWrap but it is not working for me ..If the text doesnot fit in that line then it should automatically should appear in the next line

```
UILabel *lblMyLable = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,118, 600, 40)]autorelease];
    lblMyLable.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lblMyLable.numberOfLines = 0;//Dynamic
    lblMyLable.tag=1301;
    lblMyLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblMyLable.text = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@",id,name,address,city,state,country];
    [self.view addSubview:lblMyLable];
```

But here after displaying the id ,name and address the remaining part is cut ..I couldnot see 
it ..I am searching in such a way that if doesnot fit one line then it should automatically jump to next line starting from where it was stopped in first line.How can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sh";
NSString *str1 = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sh";
NSString *str2 = @"xyz";
NSString *str3 = @"xyz";
NSString *str4 = @"xyz";
NSString *str5 = @"xyz";
NSString *str6 = @"xyz";
NSString *str7 = @"xyz";   

UILabel *lblMyLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 200, 40)];

lblMyLable.numberOfLines = 0;

lblMyLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

lblMyLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",str,str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7];

[lblMyLable sizeToFit];

[self.view addSubview:lblMyLable];
```

Comment: @arizah: Write hundrends of lines in lblMyLable.text and check it. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The hight of your `UILable` is too small to make you see the lines

set the height to a vialue bigger than `40`

```
UILabel *lblMyLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,118, 600, 240)];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
lblMyLable.numberOfLines = 0;
lblMyLable.text = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@",id,name,address,city,state,country];
[lblMyLable sizeToFit];
```